# Ninject.MVC3 Package requires MVC5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ninject

I've installed the [Ninject.MVC3 -Version 3.0.0.6](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.MVC3/3.0.0.6) package but get the following error.

```
An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in Ninject.dll 
but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I presume that this means that the version of the ninject.MVC3 package i've installed requires MVC5 which strikes me as rather odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up resolving this by manually  installing Ninject MVC using the Global.asax way of registering services as laid out [here](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Mvc/wiki/Setting-up-an-MVC3-application).